# Writing service in clojure

Tags: clojure

I am writing a simple service to retrieve images from different sources (instagram, flickr, google)

Currently every service served in a separate `.clj` file with bunch of functions, both common and specific.

I am thinking about introducing protocol `ImageService` for that and each specific service will implement that protocol. This way we could add documentation at the protocol level and reuse common methods.

What are pros and cons with using protocols for such type of problem? How do we create specific implementation for service: `deftype`, `defrecord` or `reify`? What is idiomatic approach in clojure?

Comment: How would you want to call a generic service? That is, what would the function call look like? And on what basis should the choice between the services be made in each specific case?

Answer (score 0):

We've had a great deal of success at my company using protocols over external services just like you described. Protocols are nice because they allow you to write calling code in a single agnostic fashion, and also do  dependency injection for easy testing (with mock implementations of your protocol). The main downside of protocols I've run into is that you can't have (shared) default implementations, otherwise I"m very happy with them.

`deftype` and `defrecord` differ [in several ways](http://clojure.org/datatypes#toc4), in practice the most prominent difference is that types generated with defrecord can also behave like maps:

```
(defrecord Foo [bar])
(->Foo 1) ; or (Foo. 1)
; => #user.Foo{:bar 1}
(assoc (Foo. 1) :norf 2)
; => #user.Foo{:bar 1, :norf 2}
```

Up to you if you need this behavior or not. `reify` just creates an 'anonymous' implementation of your protocol, we tend not to use it much and instead use a pattern like

```
(deftype MyService [args...])

; Our own public constructor
(defn ->my-service [config]
  (->MyService (parse-config config)))

; etc ...
```